# How to increase the speed of a HashSet when used to ensure no duplicate records are generated

Tags: c#, .net, list, hashset

I need to generate roughly 500k unique codes for each of our customers.

The code runs in a few minutes, however, I need to make sure there are no clashes, so I added this logic in to use a HashTable.
This has resulted in the peformance taking over 8 hours to generate just 200k.

Is there anything I can use to better the performance here?

The performance bottleneck is the HashSet lookup (around line 8). What other options are there to increase the performance of making sure there are no duplicates?

```
public string GenerateUniqueReferralCode(CustomerObj customer, HashSet<string> assignedCodes)
{
    bool isUnique = false;
    string code = String.Empty;
    do
    {
        code = GenerateReferralCode(customer);
        if (!assignedCodes.Contains(code))
        {
            isUnique = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isUnique = false;
        }
    } while (!isUnique);
    return code;
}

public string GenerateReferralCode(CustomerObj customer)
{
    var code = String.Empty;
    //replace special characters and only keep alpha

    var name = customer.Profile.FirstName + customer.Profile.LastName;
    name = new String(name.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());

    if (name.Length > 3)
    {
        code += name.Substring(0, 4).ToUpperInvariant();
    }
    else
    {
        code += customer.Profile.FirstName.Substring(0, customer.Profile.FirstName.Length).ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    code += CreateMD5(customer.Profile.Email + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

    code = code.Substring(0, 7);

    return code;
}
```

Comment: You understand that you're producing a string that selects the first four characters from the name and only returns 7 characters with the MD5 hash making up the last 3 characters. Since you're outputting a hex value that's only `16^3` possible values. Unless I'm missing something your code can only produce 4096 unique codes. To get 200k you must be doing something different than the code here.

Comment: Just as a benchmark - my computer can make `500_000` hash codes in just over 3 seconds. Your code should be able to do it in a similar time. `Enumerable.Range(0, 500000).Select(x => CreateMD5(x.ToString())).ToList();`

Comment: Generating a unique code with zero chance for a collision is quite simple, it is code = code + 1.  500K of them takes a fraction of a second.  What you *really* seem to try to do is not make it easy to guess what the original code value was.  It isn't clear why that is important and how strong that encryption needs to be, never take security advice from an Internet site.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I am trying to generate a customer friendly code that they can use to refer friends. Something like johnm4b2 (with the customer name being john m). I want the code to have some reference to the customers name, which is why there are clashes, because some people have the same similar names.

Comment: How many codes are you hoping to generate per customer?

Comment: @Enigmativity 1 code per customer.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.UtcNow` changes at a *glacial* rate compared to how fast a modern processor is, and this appears to be your only source of randomness in generating your codes<sup>1</sup>. There's also no way to recover this value and validate the MD5<sup>2</sup> hash anyway so I'm not sure what value it's adding.

Instead, use a cryptographic random number generator to generate some real randomness and use that in your codes. But don't forget to include the raw value in the code if you'll need to validate the hash.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which means you're highly likely to spend *ages* looping creating "new" codes that precisely match the previous code until the time changes.

<sup>2</sup>**N.B.** you should not be using MD5 in new work either...